# Ruby on rails: Rake Migrate Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to do a rake migrate, but I'm getting an error when I do this:

```
rake db:migrate
```

What I get back:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2377:in `raw_load_rakefile'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If none of the current answers help, please take the advice of the error message, run "rake db:migrate --trace" and post what you get here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you in the root directory of your project?
is there a file called Rakefile?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the current directory is within your project.

So for example:

```
cd ~/projects/greatness/
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: did you mean "rake db:migrate"?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems rather self explanatory.  There is no rakefile for rake to operate on.

If your rails structure is broken in some way, I'd suggest calling rails  in a temporary folder then bringing across the script directory and rake file.